# How can i cast System.Type in MVC Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, casting

So, i need to get an area of a controller, and i'm getting the controllers with this way:

```
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
var controllers = from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                  where type.Name.Contains("Controller")
                  select type;
```

Ok, with this way i've all controllers, but they are as Type, how can i cast in a MVC Controller? 'Cause i need to get the controller area with somthing like that:

```
string area = controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"].ToString();
```

So?

Comment: Try `DependencyResolver.Current` or the `ControllerFactory` to get controller instances.

Comment: @Steven, he doesn't need to get controller instances. He needs to determine in which area a controller belongs. This is not done through a controller instance. Even if he gets a controller instance he will then need a controller context which obviously could only be the current controller context of the current request and not just any controller context. He is just trying to do something that is possible only by inspecting the full type name of the controller through reflection.

Comment: @Steven, the `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService` get a object from a type only, not for a instance of type like i have, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot cast a Type to an instance of an object. This doesn't make sense. You might inspect the namespace into which this type is defined by looking at the `type.FullName` and is the only way to understand in which Area the controller that this Type represents is defined in. By the way checking that a given type is a controller using `type.Name.Contains("Controller")` seems pretty brittle and fragile. You'd better use `where typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type);`

Comment: Thank you! I'm think about that, but i expected another way, like DataTokens, but if this is the only way, so, ok! =)

Answer (score 0):

You can create objects of the types with

```
Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: Yes, but this won't help the OP in this case. Not only he needs an instance of the controller but he needs to use its ControllerContext property and this is only possible if you are inside an HTTP request. And even if this was the case that would return the area for the current controller and not just any controller out there.